# ERROR Spring JPA call procedure that only have OUT parameter

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I face an error while calling procedure that only have OUT parameter from spring JPA. Here is the code
Entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "M_PRODUCTS")
@NamedStoredProcedureQueries({ @NamedStoredProcedureQuery(
    name = "getProductNo",
    procedureName = "usp_get_product_no",
    parameters = {
            @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.OUT, name = "productNo", type = Long.class) }) })
public class ProductEntity implements Serializable {
```

Repository class:

```
@Repository
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<ProductEntity, UUID> {

    @Procedure(name = "getProductNo")
    Long getProductNo();

}
```

I have tried change the parameter mode to INOUT and still return the same error.

Here it the error message:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: OUT/INOUT parameter not available: 1; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: OUT/INOUT parameter not available: 1
```

The procedure it self does not have error when I tried execute by pl/sql

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_get_product_no(productNo OUT NUMBER) IS BEGIN .... END;

declare
    v_product_no number;
begin
    usp_get_product_no(v_product_no);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('v_product_no ' || v_product_no);
end;
```

Can anyone help me to find the cause?

Comment: Could you please provide the declaration of your procedure in pl/sql ?

Comment: @SternK  added script